# Repeating code N times selenium WD in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

```
public WebDriver Loopthisstuff (Webdriver driver, int X) {
   additem.click();
   WebElement answerX = driver.findElement(By.id("item_rowX_txt"));
   answerX.sendKeys("ITEM NR X");
}
```

I am kinda new to coding,I am looking for a method to loop this piece NTIMES.
The nature of the site is that every time you additem.click() it creates a new texfield with id "item_rowX_txt" with X increasing by one each time.

I also have to fill these fields with the SendKeys command.
Any tips please? I have just started learning java and working with selenium. ( tried to make the code as little as I could). I did some googling about looping N times but I dont know how to implement it for a class, and how to use the same variable (X) at those places you see in the code.

Comment: It's called a "for loop"

Comment: Follow [this](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-for-loop/) to understand looping

Answer (score 0):

Before starting with selenium it is expected to have knowledge of any programming language, in this case JAVA. 
But you can try below solution:

```
//assuming that X is the number of times you want to execute the loop

public WebDriver Loopthisstuff (Webdriver driver, int X) {
//also assuming that the ID of first textbox is "item_row0_txt"
for(int i=0;i<X;i++)
{
    additem.click();
    WebElement answerX = driver.findElement(By.id("item_row"+i+"_txt"));
    answerX.sendKeys("ITEM NR "+i);
}
}
```